# Android - Bitmap Height = Textview Text Height?

Tags: android, bitmap, textview, height, scale

Adding an image in a text view works. Changing the image height and width to text view text height not works. (Original Image "red circle" is: 32px x 32px)

Output looks like this:

[test img http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/9500/m1f.png](http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/9500/m1f.png)

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Code:

```
TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);   
}

@Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);  

    String getText = getResources().getString(R.string.getText);

    textView.setText(getText);

    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(getText);

    Bitmap redcircle= BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.redcircle );

    Bitmap resizedbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(redcircle, (int)textView.getMeasuredHeight(), (int)textView.getMeasuredHeight(), true);
    ssb.setSpan( new ImageSpan( resizedbitmap ), 3, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );    

    textView.setText( ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE );      
}
```

EDIT:

I want, that the image height and width is equal text view text height. For example like this:

[test img 2 http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/3163/r9x.png](http://img849.imageshack.us/img849/3163/r9x.png)

Comment: instead of textView.getMeasuredHeight(), use as textView.getLineHeight()

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
ImageSpan(resizedbitmap, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE)
```

instead of

```
ImageSpan(resizedbitmap)
```

The default alignment of an `ImageSpan` is `ALIGN_BOTTOM`.

Comment: Ok. But the image size is the same. It not gets the text view height.

Comment: @user2080833 - When you use styled text, the image becomes part of the text; if the text view has padding, then that padding will be applied to the image as well. Perhaps you could post a drawing of exactly what you're trying to achieve.